# AWS CLI to fetch EC2 instance details

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I am using the AWS CLI to fetching EC2 instance details. My requirements are:

**1) Fetch only running EC2 instances:**

- instance id
- instance tag
- instance type
- availability zone
- blockdevices name
- platform
- reserved or ondemand

However I can't able to fetch last 3 attributes (blockdevices name, platform and reserved or ondemand). When I add it in my query it is showing None. What do I need to change in query?

My query is:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`] | [0].Value,InstanceId,State.Name,InstanceType,Placement.AvailabilityZone]" --output table > output.txt
```

The output is:

```
|  test1 |  i-xxxxxxx  |  m1.small   |  running |  us-east-1a  |
|  test2 |  i-xxxxx    |  m1.large   |  running |  us-east-1c  |
|  test3 |  i-xxxxx    |  m1.xlarge  |  running |  us-east-1c  |
|  test4 |  i-xxxxxxx  |  m3.2xlarge |  running |  us-east-1a  |
```

**2) Need to fetch each instance price** considering those attributes  (region,type,ondemand/reserved) and put full instance details in a CSV file.

Answer (score 2):

**Blockdevices name**

I'm not sure what you mean by "name", but there is a `DeviceName` field:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].BlockDeviceMappings[*].DeviceName
```

**Platform**

The `Platform` field is either `Windows` or undefined (for Linux):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --query Reservations[*].Instances[*].Platform
```

**Reserved or On-Demand**

This is a **billing concept** and is not available for an instance. In fact, an instance could be billed as On-Demand in one hour and as a Reserved Instance in another hour.

The basic concept is that, for each Reserved Instance owned by an account, the billing system looks for a running Amazon EC2 instance that matches the Reserved Instance parameters. The matching instance is not charged the hourly fee for that hour. This information can be seen in the billing files, but is not available as information against the instance.

Make sure you have turned on [Detailed Billing Reports](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/billing-reports.html) so that you can receive this level of billing information. It is only available *after* the reports have been activated (not back in time).

**Fetch the price**

There is no command to fetch the price of a running Amazon EC2 instance. There is a [Price List API](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-price-list-api/) that provides pricing information similar to the pricing pages on the AWS website.

You could write a program to fetch the prices via the Price List API and determine which price is appropriate for an instance. However, as stated above, the program would not know whether an instance was running as a Reserved Instance.

**Put full instance details in a CSV file**

The AWS CLI does not output CSV format. You would have to post-process the output into the desired format. Note that some of your information (eg BlockDevices) might return multiple values for a single instance.

Comment: Hi John, as you said there is block device name to fetch device name . I am using this but value is coming null I think there is some error in my script . Below is my script  ' aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=instance-state-name,Values=running" --query "Reservations[].Instances[].[Tags[?Key==`Name`] | [0].Value,InstanceId,State.Name,InstanceType,BlockDeviceMappings.DeviceName,Placement.AvailabilityZone]" > output.txt '

Comment: There seem to be several errors -- for example, use `Reservations[*].Instances[*]` with the `*` character. Best way to get a command like that working is to break it into smaller bits (like my examples) and then put it together when you know that each field is working correctly.